# How to refresh Winforms custom controls in Rider ide 2020.1.2

Tags: winforms, custom-controls, rider

I am running JetBrains Rider 2020.1.2, Build #RD-201.7223.10, built on May 6, 2020 and working on a custom control.   The IDE doesn't seem to update the property grid with design-time changes to my control.  If I open and close the file, the changes will reflect.  Whereas if I make the change and perform a build/run, changes will not reflect in properties grid for the control at design time.   Is it possible for someone to cast some light on this?

```
[Category("Design"), Description("Turn on dark mode."),Browsable(true)]
public bool DarkMode { get; set; }
```

I.e. if I add the above.

[image: After property added, build and run.]

[image: After property added, file closed and reopened]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a reload designer option in the top right.

[image]